# Error Initializing Java Tooling. Reason: assertion failed: Path for IClasspathEntry must be absolute

Tags: java, eclipse

After migrating the workspace from windows to mac, got the error that:

> Error Initializing Java Tooling. Reason: assertion failed: Path for IClasspathEntry must be absolute

The projects got displayed as empty projects in Eclipse. Is there a way to get around this problem, without recreating the workspace and reimporting the projects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Initially I was thinking that this was an issue with .classpath file. But, the classpath file did not have an entry with the offending file. But the entry was in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web/webLibrariesCache.index

file of the workspace.

I deleted the file and was able to open the workspace successfully and see the project.

Comment: Worked for me. For anybody who wants to copy-paste your file path (like me): `.metedata` must be `.metadata`.

Comment: I deleted the content from the .plugins folder and the problem is solved for me.